# Manually deal with redirect from webforms login

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an old webforms project with a login page that had a login control:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DestinationPageUrl="~/Web/Default.aspx">
    <LayoutTemplate>Username:<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
            <br />
            Password:<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>                       
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" />
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
```

I would like to perform some functions prior to the automatic redirect. How can I achieve that? The button has no code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the control in design view and check the properties tab's Events button (lightning bolt). There are a few events there including

```
LoggingIn
Authenticate
LoggedIn
```

That's the order of events. I think redirect doesn't happen until after LoggedIn.

Answer (score 0):

You can put javascript functions on your button.

```
 <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" onclick='yourFunction();' CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" />
```

//Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript>

function yourFunction(){

 //your transaction

}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Check This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx.aspx)

you can redirect either to aspx or html pages